# C++ compiler error regarding initialization of a non-const reference of type 'std::ostream&' from a temporary of type 'std::ostream"

Tags: c++, ostream

I've been attempting to create a program that implements a real-time scheduling algorithm for a defined set of processes. While compiling with g++ I get an error, which states:

RTSprocess.h: in function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const rtsProcess&)':
RTSprocess.h84: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::ostream&' from a temporary of type 'std::ostream*'

```
#ifndef RTSPROCESS_H
#define RTSPROCESS_H
//defining the rts process


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
//include the necessary parts

using namespace std;

//create the rts process class itself, declare all necessary variables
class rtsProcess {
protected:
public:
    int pid;
    int burst;
    int arrival;
    int timeRemaining;
    int doneWaiting;
    int finishTime;
    int deadline;
    bool failed;

    //assign base values to all necessary variables
    rtsProcess() {
        this->failed = false;
        this->pid = 0;
        this->burst = 0;
        this->arrival = 0;
        this->timeRemaining =0;
        this->doneWaiting = 0;
        this->finishTime = 0;
        this->deadline = 0;
    };

    //set case where variables assigned by user
    rtsProcess (int pid, int burst, int arrival, int deadline) {
        this->pid = pid;
        this->burst = burst;
        this->arrival = arrival;
        this->timeRemaining = burst;
        this->deadline = deadline;
        this->doneWaiting = 0;
        this->finishTime = 0;
        this->failed = false;
    };
    ~rtsProcess() {

    };
    //set case where input from file
    rtsProcess( const rtsProcess &p) {
        pid = p.pid;
        burst = p.burst;
        arrival = p.arrival;
        timeRemaining = p.timeRemaining;
        deadline = p.deadline;
        doneWaiting = p.doneWaiting;
        finishTime = p.finishTime;
        failed = p.failed;
    };
    // set with return
    rtsProcess& operator = (const rtsProcess &p) {
        pid = p.pid;
        burst = p.burst;
        arrival = p.arrival;
        timeRemaining = p.timeRemaining;
        deadline = p.deadline;
        doneWaiting = p.doneWaiting;
        finishTime = p.finishTime;
        failed = p.failed;
        return *this;
    };
    //set the operators
    bool operator== (const rtsProcess &p) {
        return (this->pid == p.pid && this->arrival == p.arrival && this->burst == p.burst);
    }
    bool operator!= (const rtsProcess &p){
        return !(this->pid == p.pid && this->arrival == p.arrival && this->burst == p.burst);
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const rtsProcess &p) {
        p.display(os);
        return &os;
    };
    //set the display to the console
    void display(ostream &os) const {
        os << "\t" << pid;
        os << "\t" << burst;
        os << "\t" << arrival;
        os << "\t" << deadline;
        os << "\t\t" << timeRemaining;
    };
};
#endif
```

From what I can tell it seems as though the error lies in this block of code(also the error message explicitly mentions it):

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const rtsProcess &p) {
    p.display(os);
    return &os;
};
```

I have attempted every way that I can think of to correct the error, changing the type passed to p.display doesn't work, changing the return type doesn't seem to work, and I'm kind of at my wit's end. I've found answers here that reference similar things, but none whose solutions seem to fix my issue. Any help in solving my error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Parameter `os` is a reference. Function returns a reference. You don't need `&` before `os`.

Comment: (I'm talking about `operator<<`, ofc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const rtsProcess &p) {
    p.display(os);
    return &os;
};
```

to

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const rtsProcess &p) {
    p.display(os);
    return os;
};
```

Operator `&` is called address of. Returning a reference is different from returning an address yielding to your compiler error.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe it was something so small and stupid as that, but it shows that I need to heavily invest more time in c/c++ coding.

Comment: There is no such thing as "c/c++".

Comment: @KiernanJ.Johnson c++ is a beast, you need to be patient and eventually you will get there :) Good luck mate !

Comment: "You don't need the address of & operator in order to return a reference." Not only does he not need it, he can't have it.

Comment: @jensa that's what i meant, address of operator is different than the returning a reference, although it was a good notice, i will do an edit :)

Comment: @KostasRim Okay perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out in the first comment to your post, don't do

```
return &os; // this creates a temporary pointer to os
```

Just do

```
return os;
```

Whenever you do

```
&x
```

where x is some variable you get a temporary pointer to that variable. Hence the error message

> RTSprocess.h84: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of **type 'std::ostream&' from a temporary of type 'std::ostream*'**

The compiler therefore realized that you are trying to return a pointer when the function returns a reference and it throws you an error.